# When adding bootstrap class the element disappears reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I just started using react.js and bootstrap. I am trying to add a badge to a span, so i add `className ="badge badge-primary badge-dark m-2"` but when i do so the element disappears.

[image: Before adding]

[image: After Adding]

[image: After adding highlighted]

As you can see the first picture is the one without the class name, the second with the className and the thid is with the className but i highlighted it. So the element is still there, it is just hidden. Does anyone know why this is the case and how i can solve it? I tried on edge and firefox but the issue was still there.

Bootstrap version: 5.1.3
broswer: firefox 101.0.1

full code:

```
class Counter extends Component {
    state = { 
        count: 0,
    };

    render() { 
        return (
            <div>
                <span className ="badge badge-primary badge-dark m-2">{this.formatCount()}</span>
                <button className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Increment</button> 
            </div>
        );
    }

    formatCount() {
        const { count } = this.state;
        return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you just started using react please don't learn class components. Just skip them and go to functional components and hooks

Comment: I can't test it right know, but try to remove badge-primary class

Comment: @IgorGonak I was using a tutorial from codingwithmosh, do you think i should still skip that? I tried removing it but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Changing `className ="badge badge-primary badge-dark m-2"` to `className ="badge bg-primary badge-dark m-2"` solved it for me